# Quantitative Time-series data, duration of states

Tags: r, time-series, sequence

I have a longitudinal dataset with a time variable and a qualitative variable. My subject can be in one of three states, sometimes the state changes, sometimes it stays the same.

What I would like to produce is a new dataframe which gives me, for every time a subject is in a state, at what time it first was in that state and how long the subject stayed in that same state.  I want to do this because my end goal is to see whether state-switches occur more/less often for different treatments, length of states differ per state, length of states changes over time, etcetera.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
Data=data.frame(time=1:100,State=sample(c('a','b','c'),100,replace=TRUE))
```

The first few lines of Data look like this

> ```
>        time       State
> 1      1          a
> 2      2          b
> 3      3          b
> 4      4          c
> 5      5          a
> 6      6          c
> 7      7          c
> ```

I would like to produce this:

> ```
>        StartTime  State    Duration
> 1      1          a        1
> 2      2          b        2
> 3      4          c        1
> 4      5          a        1
> 5      6          c        2
> ```

I can probably achieve this with a while-loop but this seems highly inefficient, especially since my actual data is 700000 lines per subject. Is there a better way to do it? Maybe something with the diff-function and %in%. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
Data=data.frame(time=1:100,State=sample(c('a','b','c'),100,replace=TRUE))
```

Use data.table with data of that size:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)
head(Data)
#   time State
#1:    1     a
#2:    2     b
#3:    3     b
#4:    4     c
#5:    5     a
#6:    6     c
```

Give each state run a number:

```
Data[, state_run := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.integer(Data$State)) != 0L))]
#Note that this assumes that State is a factor variable
```

Find the values of interest for each state run:

```
Data2 <- Data[, list(StartTime = min(time),
                     State = State[1],
                     Duration = diff(range(time)) + 1), by = state_run]
head(Data2)
#   state_run StartTime State Duration
#1:         1         1     a        1
#2:         2         2     b        2
#3:         3         4     c        1
#4:         4         5     a        1
#5:         5         6     c        2
#6:         6         8     b        2
```